# Why a matrix-by-matrix derivative is actually a tensor?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, tensors, multilinear-algebra

For matrices $A$ and $B$, I thought $\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}$ is a matrix $C$ where $C_{ij} = \frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial B_{ij}}$.

However, when I use this [matrix calculus website](http://www.matrixcalculus.org), it says

$$\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{A}} = \mathbb{I}\otimes\mathbb{I}$$

Why is it a tensor? How to select the elements from this tensor to get the kind of derivative $C$ that I thought about?

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial B}$ is a rank 4 tensor $\dfrac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial B_{kl}}$, because in general $A_{ij}$ can have nontrivial dependence on entries other than $B_{ij}$.

Comment: Can I use some kind of trace to select the elements $\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial B_{ij}}$ from the tensor and form a matrix?

Comment: If you want the derivative of entry $(i,j)$ of $A$ with respect to entry $(k,l)$ of $B$, then you need a $4$-tuple $(i,j,k,l)$ to index all the derivatives, i.e., you need a $4$-dimensional matrix. Some would call such a matrix a tensor.

Comment: You can certainly extract the elements $\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial B_{ij}}$, $1\leq i,j\leq n$ and lump them into a matrix.  However, it won't behave like a matrix (e.g. you don't get a chain rule).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, $C_{i_1\cdots i_pj_1\cdots j_q}:=\frac{\partial A_{i_1\cdots i_p}}{\partial B_{j_1\cdots j_q}}$ shows the derivative of a rank-$p$ tensor with respect to a rank-$q$ tensor is a rank-$p+q$ tensor. If any of your indices on $A$ match those on $B$, that implies you're not calculating one element of $C$, but rather summing over all values of any repeated index. This is true even if one tensor is proportional to another. Returning to your example with matrices, if a scalar $c$ exists with $A_{ij}=cB_{ij}$ then $\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial B_{kl}}=c\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$ (provided the entries in any one matrix are independent, so they aren't e.g. symmetric), but $\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial B_{ij}}=c\delta_{ii}\delta_{jj}$ is $c$ times the number of entries per matrix.